# validation rules from config file doesnot set errors

Tags: php, forms, validation, continuous-integration, codeigniter-2

I am trying to validate a form through config. When i submit blank input field,it just shoes same page. I needs errors displayed in add_article.php Help....

**config/form_validation.php**

```
<?php

$config = [
        'add_article_rules' => [
                                    [
                                        'field' => 'title',
                                        'label' => 'Article Title',
                                        'rules' => 'required|alphadash'
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'field' => 'body',
                                        'label' => 'Article Body',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                    ]

        ]

];
```

My Controller (admin.php)

```
<?php 
class Admin extends MY_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if(! $this->session->userdata('user_id')){

        return redirect('login');
    }
}

public function dashboard(){
    $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');

    $articles= $this->articles->article_list();

    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',['articles'=>$articles]);

}

public function add_article(){
    $this->load->view('admin/add_article');

}

public function store_article(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    if($this->form_validation->run('add_article_rules')){
            //if sucesss
    }else{

        return redirect('admin/add_article');

    }
}

public function edit_select(){}

public function edit_article(){}

public function delete_article(){}
}
```

View file (add_article.php)

```
<?php require_once('admin_header.php'); ?>

<div class="container">
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo form_open('admin/store_article',['class'=>'form-horizontal']); ?>
        <?php echo form_hidden('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));?>               
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Add Article</legend>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Title</label>
                          <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <?php 
                                $data = array(
                                  'name'        => 'title',                                   
                                  'class'       => 'form-control',
                                  'value'       => set_value('title'),
                                  'placeholder'       => 'Username'                           

                                );
                                echo form_input($data);
                            ?>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Article Body</label>
                          <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <?php 
                                $data = array(
                                  'name'        => 'body',
                                  'value'       => set_value('body'),
                                  'class'       => 'form-control',
                                  'placeholder'       => 'Article Body',


                                );
                                echo form_textarea($data);
                            ?>


                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?php echo form_error('body'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4">
                             <?php 
                                $data = array(
                                  'name'        => 'reset',                           
                                  'class'       => 'btn btn-default',
                                  'value'       => 'Reset',


                                );
                                echo form_reset($data);
                            ?>

                            <?php 
                                $data = array(
                                  'name'        => 'submit',                              
                                  'class'       => 'btn btn-primary',
                                  'value'       => 'Submit',


                                );
                                echo form_submit($data);
                            ?>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>
</div>


<?php require_once('admin_footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just Change Admin Controller method and view file

// View File in add_article.php
 <?php echo form_open(); ?>

//Controller File
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function add_article()
    {
        if ($this->form_validation->run('add_article_rules')) {
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin/add_article');
        }
    }

    public function edit_select()
    {
    }

    public function edit_article()
    {
    }

    public function delete_article()
    {
    }
}
```